# I do not know this symbol PHP

Tags: php

many times I've seen this symbol `->`

What is it? seems a logical operator or something

Complete example:

```
get_categories->category_count
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called the `object operator`.

For example:

```
$myObject = new stdClass();
$myObject->Hello = "world";

echo $myObject->Hello; //Returns world
```

You can also use this operator to call properties or methods from classes. For example:

```
Class MyClass {

  public function hello(){
      return "world";
  }

}

echo (new MyClass())->hello(); //Returns world
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called as PHP object operator (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR).

Example:

```
$car = new Car();
$car->color = 'Red';
echo $car->color; // returns the color of the car.
```

Comment: PHP has only 1 object operator (the first). The second one is called the scope resolution operator.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'll update now.